# How do I find the initial conditions for linear homogeneous recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

So I have this equation:

$$a_n = −a_{n−1 } + 6a_{n−2}$$

How do I find the solution to this? Everywhere I look, everyone is using some initial conditions to solve it, but I don't get those in my paper, only this equation.

Comment: Well I think some initial terms are necessary for a recurrence.

Comment: For instance $f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$ is different when you have different initial terms...

Comment: i don't know anything about that, but i just can't understand i don't have any a_0 = something and a_1 = something etc...

Comment: That's the problem @Linexxlol. You need initial conditions for a recurrence to proceed AFAIK

Comment: but how does that make sense then, this is a assignment from my university teacher, why would he not give inital conditions?

Comment: When formulated like this, it means that you take two parameters, namely $a_0$ and $a_1$, and find $a_n$ as a function of $n$, $a_0$, and $a_1$.